# return value ignored: 'scanf' (closed)

Tags: c, scanf, warnings, compiler-warnings, getchar

I'm writing a program with C and this is one of my functions:

```
void group3()
{
    char select[5];
    printf("\nDetails etc.");
    printf("\nPlease confirm Yes/No if you would like to subscribe:");
    scanf("%s", select);
    if (select == "Yes")
        printf("Good.");
    else
    {
        printf("Alright.");
        main();
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile and debug the program, a warning called "return value ignored: 'scanf'" appears. I noticed that the warning appears when I'm running scanf for integers too but the program still works for integers. However, when I try to scanf for strings, it doesn't work.  I've tried using getchar() but the same warning occurs for getchar(). I've also tried using scanf_s but the same problem appears when I try to scanf_s for strings. I've also defined _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in my program. Would really appreciate it if someone could explain to me how I can eliminate this warning from occurring/get the scanf or getchar to work with strings.

**edit: thanks to some helpful users i found out that the problem isn't because the string wasn't read, but because i cannot compare strings using the if statement this way. the answer is in the comment section and i can't select it as the correct answer to this but this question is closed. thank you :)**

Comment: out of that do you really want to call `main()` in your function ???

Comment: @user3121023 thanks for the advice. :) however i'm still looking for a solution as to why scanf isn't reading the string here because if scanf doesn't read the string i still can't use the if statement for it

Comment: @user3121023 ohh okay i tried it out and i get what you mean now! it was my mistake, sorry and tysm!! i rly appreciate it, have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the return value of `scanf()` is ignored, so don't ignore that to eliminate the warning.

`scanf()` returns the number of data read on success and negative number on error, so it is useful to check if it successfully read required things.

Example:

```
    if (scanf("%4s", select) != 1) {
        fputs("read error\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
```

Also it is good to read the length to read to avoid buffer overrun.
This is also done in the above example.

One more point is that `select == "Yes"` is not a correct way to compare strings in C.
This is comparing pointers and it won't be true because the array and the string literal are stored in differenct places in memory.
[`strcmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) function from `string.h` is useful to compare strings.

Comment: may be also a remark in your answer about the call of *main* ?

Comment: @bruno Calling `main()` recursively is allowed in C. I cannot say that this is wrong from this code.

Comment: at least this is suspicious ;-)

Comment: sorry i'm kind of new to C so i'm not rly sure what you mean but i tried running the code above with my program and no error message nor negative number pops up... how to i fix the error of scanf not successfully reading the string?

Comment: @cmy in the current case scanf will not success if you reach end of file before its call, only you can decide what to do in that case ;-)

Comment: @MikeCAT hi, i just found out that the problem isn't because the string wasn't read, but because i shouldn't have used the if statement that way. i do appreciate your word of advice tho! tysm, have a nice day! :)